# Date and time validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, validation, datetime

I am trying to do date validation.

My requirement is user should not be able to select past date and time. It works fine until I change my local PC's date and time.

I am comparing user selected date and time with `new Date()` object of javascript but found that it fetches date from local machine's date. So if user changes his local machines date(set it to past date) then he would be able to select past dates.

Any server side(Java) solution is also acceptable. Try that too but Java's date object(java.util.date) also fetches date from local machine's date so no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your application is deployed? If you call new Date() then it will give the date of that machine (Server). So it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you should get date and time from server.

**serverDateTime.js**

```
var xmlHttp;
function srvTime(){
    try {
        //FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (err1) {
        //IE
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch (err2) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch (eerr3) {
                //AJAX not supported, use CPU time.
                alert("AJAX not supported");
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open('HEAD',window.location.href.toString(),false);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    xmlHttp.send('');
    return xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date");
}
var st = srvTime();
var date = new Date(st);
```

**Html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Server date/time</title>
<script language="javascript" src="serverDateTime.js"></script>
</head>
<script language="javascript">
var localTime = new Date();
document.write("Local machine time is: " + localTime + "<br>");
document.write("Server time is: " + date);
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will work.
Source : [webdeveloper](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?228309-Getting-server-date-time-with-no-server-side-script)

Comment: from which server it is getting date and time?

Comment: If you are running on your local machine then it will be your computer date and time.

Comment: No I have changed my local machine's date but your code returns the right date. Can you tell me how?

Comment: try changing date and then restart server. May be it will reflect changed date and time after that.